# How to pass parameter from MVC to Silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight

After MVC project authentication, i need a solution on how to pass parameters secure after button click

I did it bellow code

```
<form action="http://localhost:53988/Default.aspx" method="post" -- this is where is hosted SilverlightApp>
    <input type="hidden" name="session" value="@(Helpers.Context.CurrentSession.ID)"/>
    <input type="submit" value="RedirectToSilver" />
</form>
```

in Silverlight aspx page (Default.aspx) I get this parameter

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/Client.xap?<%=AssemblyInfo.GetVersionNumber()%>" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
          <param name="initParams" value="sessionId = '<%=HttpContext.Current.Request["session"] %>'" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
    </object>
</div>
```

and in app.xaml.cs

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var sessionID= string.Empty;
    if (e.InitParams.ContainsKey("sessionId"))
        sessionID= e.InitParams["sessionId"];
}
```

everything works but problem is that client can see sessionID and i think this is not secure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQY70.jpg

my goal is to  get this sessionID securitly in silverlight without showing it to client? how to do it?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be secure? You're passing it from your MVC over plaintext HTTP anyway, and it does need to end up in Silverlight. The client will be able to inspect the session id anyway.

Comment: you can see image I've posted http://i.stack.imgur.com/UQY70.jpg, I don't know is it secure that client can see session or some secure information?

Comment: The client can see their session id using a cookie editor in their browser anyway.

Comment: this sessionId is Id(Guid) from table in SQL Server not value of HttpContext.Current.Session if I it explained correctly

Comment: Look; what I mean is that the Silverlight app will be making requests using that session id again, so there's little use in hiding it anyway. And you need to pass it from the web page to the Silverlight app anyway, so you _cannot_ hide it. You can obfuscate it, for example using encryption, but your Silverlight app will then have to decrypt it in order to use it, where a user with a debugger can read the value from memory again.

Comment: Is there any chance to hide it? for example if I can get values from initParams in Application_Startup event, can i somehow get directly sessionid without storing it in initParams?

Answer (score 0):

Create an action to return the session id and have the silverlight client call that endpoint to get the current session id.

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
public class SessionController : Controller {

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get() {
        return Json(Helpers.Context.CurrentSession.ID);
    }

}
```

**Client**

```
private async void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) {
    var sessionID = string.Empty;
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var url = "http://localhost:53988/Session";
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode 
       && response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.GetValueOrDefault() > 0) {
        sessionID = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

You can either hard code the endpoint or make it discoverable, that is up to you. Also the sample I showed assumes that you are not using WebApi. That should be easy enough for you to implement if you wanted.
I personally believe that all this running around trying to hide the session id is pointless, but again I don't know your circumstances.